# Deleted questions and question ban

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, post-ban

I've seen a number of question on the meta where people do not understand the reason for being question-banned. The investigation then reveals that they have a number of deleted questions with lots of downvotes.

A deleted question cannot be improved, so the users cannot get out of the question ban.

I am not sure exactly how the ban works, but it seems that some way out of this should be available...

I would propose two features:

- A deleted question can only contribute to one ban. Once that ban period expires, the deleted question no longer counts.
- A warning can be provided to low reputation users that would discourage them from deleting their own question and explain that even a deleted question will affect the ban. The warning should encourage the user to improve the question rather than delete it.

(I apologize if all of this is already taken care of by existing ban rules. I have no experience with question bans...)

Comment: I do not understand why people do not understand the reason for being question-banned.  It seems obvious that 'deleted' questions would count towards a ban, else any old crap could be continually posted in the hope of getting an answer from the rep-peronalServicesWorkers before deletion and avoidance of any penalty/disincentive.   It's just amazing that all such meta posters are unable to remember deleting their bad, downvoted questions....

Comment: @MartinJames Some bad questions are closed then deleted by community/scripts. As to the self-deleted questions, that could be a panic reaction.

Comment: Self deletion is actually rather light weight. Community deletion is what weights heavily, as it takes 5 users to close vote, a user to downvote, and 3 20k users to delete vote. That is a lot of time wasted.

Comment: "A warning can be provided to low reputation users that would discourage them from deleting their own question and explain that even a deleted question will affect the ban.". This already happens.  When a user starts to get near the threshold of a question ban, the system warns them of that fact, this warning is often ignored.  Those same users often will then come complain about the unfair actions of the community, how they were not given a chance to improve, and not even acknowledge that perhaps thier own actions are the reason for the question ban.

Comment: the ban period does not expire. If you are missing this critical piece of information about the ban (along with the warnings users get as they approach it, the warnings they get on deletion, and so on) perhaps you shouldn't be suggesting changes to how it works?

Answer (score 2):

> The investigation then reveals that they have a number of deleted questions with lots of downvotes.

Deletion or not, the post is going to have a very high negative impact on one's ability to continue asking questions. If you can't write good questions, it's best you sit in the sidelines for a while to watch (or read) the questions that are good questions and are possible examples for the Help Center articles for asking a proper question (and four bonus articles too).

> A deleted question cannot be improved, so the users cannot get out of the question ban.

Yes it can! Taking myself as an example, I can edit my *own recently deleted questions* and if I think they are of high enough quality that matches the requirements of the site, I would take a risk and undelete it. In this case, I rather take on a few more downvotes than never learning what I did wrong. And how do I do that? I learn from the users who comment under my post, leaving suggestions on how to improve next time. There is a chance though for the post to basically revive itself, going all the way up even to a positive score!

> A warning can be provided to low reputation users that would discourage them from deleting their own question and explain that even a deleted question will affect the ban. The warning should encourage the user to improve the question rather than delete it.

This is quite subjective. A question with a score like -10 should surely be deleted quickly. No user, new or old, should ever think that the question they posted was even salvageable. All you can do now is learn and to improve. But when does deletion more risky than a downvoted post? That's the true question here is up to the user who has a clear knowledge of one's question history.

> A deleted question can only contribute to one ban. Once that ban period expires, the deleted question no longer counts.

True, this may help. But one must remember that they can be improved. Of course, if the question was voted to be deleted or was undeleted then deleted again, the question should have an very high negative impact or extend the ban. This may not be needed because a deleted question may be quickly overturned by better quality questions in the future. Bans aren't infinite and I really do hope that not all of the questions have been deleted...

---

Of course, once the ban has been casted, there's no real escape except for these cliche phrases:

- Edit your downvoted posts
- Learn from your mistakes
- Learn from your peers
- Do better next time
- Read the Help Center

Regardless of the user who is being banned, there really anything else you can do. It's put simply as learn and improve.